# Finding a path for an integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, contour-integration

It is possible to find paths for wich the following two line integral are equal to zero?

$$\int_C xy^2dx+ydy=0$$

$$\int_C \frac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2+y^2}=0$$

Could somebody give me a path for each that satisfaces or tell me why this isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one note that $y\,dy=d\bigl({1\over2}y^2\bigr)$. Therefore we take a path $C$ parallel to the $y$-axis (hence $dx=0$ along $C$) connecting two points $(a,\pm b)$, e.g., the segment from$(0,-1)$ to $(0,1)$.

In the second integral we are integrating $\nabla{\rm arg}$ along $C$; hence the value of the integral is the total increment of the polar angle along $C$. This value is $=0$ for any closed $C$ that does not go around the origin.

Comment: Excuse me, and we can make a path from (0,0) to (1,1) with the same condition for the first? And for the second from (-1,0) to (1,0)? And for any arbitrary points (a,b), (c,d)?

Comment: Thanks a lot. For the solution.